# Can CIDetector returns more than one CIFeature of type CIDetectorTypeRectangle?

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, cidetector

I also found this question [on Apple Dev Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/56394).

Is it possible for a `CIDetector` set with `CIDetectorTypeRectangle` to return more than just one rectangle?

At the moment, this code always return a `feature.count` of `0` or `1`, even if the picture is full of rectangles.

```
let context = CIContext()
let opts = [CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyHigh]
let detector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeRectangle, context: context, options: opts)
let image = CIImage(image: self.photoTaken)
let features = detector.features(in: image)

print(features.count) // never more than 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this talk in WWDC (http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/514), it is limited to only one rectangle.

Here is a quote for that:

> So we've created a generic rectangle detector object and it takes one
>   option parameter which is the aspect ratio that we want to search for.
>
> And again, you can ask the detector to return the features array.
>
> Now right now, it just returns one rectangle but that may change in
>   the future.

Comment: Yep that was I understood when I saw there was no answer on the Apple Dev Forum... Hoping the futur will arrive soon enough, it's been 2 years now! Thanks Joe.